# How to merge *.svg files created by java async profiler?

Tags: java, async-profiler

I am using [kubectl-flame](https://github.com/yahoo/kubectl-flame) to run [async-profiler](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler) on k8s pods.

When profiling a microservice that runs multiple replicas - I have a separate *.svg flamegraph for each pod.

QUESTION: Is there a way to merge those *.svg files into one graph?

Answer (score 0):

Since version 2.0, released more than a year ago, async-profiler no longer generates `svg` output. It now creates Flame Graphs on HTML 5 Canvas. Such graphs are smaller in size and a [way more responsive](https://twitter.com/AndreiPangin/status/1292994175403790337) comparing to `svg`.

As to merging, it is much easier with another format supported by async profiler - collapsed stacks. Use `-o collapsed` profiler option to dump output in that format.
Then, to merge profiles in `collapsed` format, just concatenate the corresponding output files.

A flame graph can be constructed from `collapsed` output with a [converter](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/releases/download/v2.7/converter.jar) included in async-profiler package. Here is how to do it:

```
java -cp converter.jar FlameGraph input.collapsed output.html
```

Comment: yes, but when you run async profiler with kubectl flame plugin - there is no option to choose html output format

Comment: @ludenus Well, you can modify kubectl-flame to add this option, or just use async-profiler alone, it [supports containers](https://github.com/jvm-profiling-tools/async-profiler/#profiling-java-in-a-container) out of the box.